# Clip videos using azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I've uploaded & encoded a video as an asset using AMS's AdaptiveStreaming preset to be able to stream the whole video.

I now need to split the video into short clips that will need be streamed as well. How do I go about it?

*(The start & end times of the video-clips are known.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your clips going to be at arbitrary in/out points (eg. start at 3 seconds 22 frames into the input video, and stop 18 seconds 12 frames)? If so, you would need to use the original video source, and follow the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-advanced-encoding-with-mes#trim_video). As indicated in that article, you would have to start with one of the presets where the bitrates, resolutions etc. are explicitly defined. At this time, we don't support the ability to combine clipping/trimming with the "Adaptive Streaming" preset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That link uses the v2 APIs though -- is this also possible with the v3 APIs?